# DataSource.getInheritsFrom() fails with ClassCastException

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

In SmartGwtEE project I have hierarchy of DataSources described in .ds.xml files, here is some of them:

**BaseElement_DS.ds.xml**

```
 <DataSource ID="BaseElement_DS" serverConstructor="com.isomorphic.jpa.JPADataSource"
    beanClassName="lnudb.server.model.BaseElement">
    <fields>
        <field name="id" type="sequence" hidden="true" primaryKey="true" />
        <field name="name" type="text" title="Name" required="true" />
        <field name="dsId" type="text" title="Datasource" hidden="true"/>
    </fields>
 </DataSource>
```

**Human_DS.ds.xml**

```
<DataSource ID="Human_DS" serverConstructor="com.isomorphic.jpa.JPADataSource"
    beanClassName="org.zasadnyy.lnudb.server.model.Human" inheritsFrom="BaseElement_DS"
    useParentFieldOrder="true">
    <fields>
        <field name="surname" type="text" />
        <field name="birthday" type="date" title="Birthday" required="false" />
    </fields>
</DataSource>
```

**Problem:** when I try to get parent datasource id in code

```
String parentDsId = DataSource.get("Human_DS").getInheritsFrom();
```

ClassCastExeption is raised from inside of getInheritsFrom() method:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

*I will be grateful for any help.*

Answer (score 0):

This way you won't get the exception any longer:

```
String parentDsId = DataSource.get("Human_DS").getInheritsFrom() + "";
```

However, I'm not sure whether this is "ok" for your purposes. If this is not good for you, try to create a Javascript object and assign the before mentioned value to it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but this didn't help, such solution can help in JavaScript but not in Java.